# Plotting Data through a Histogram

Tags: python, plot, histogram

The question is:  write a function (plotRandomNumbers) that uses a loop to
generate a list of random numbers, and plots those random numbers in a histogram with 20 buckets (i.e.
20 counted ranges).

So far, the code I have is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotRandomNumbers(N):
    values=list()
    i=1
    while i<=N:
        values.append(generateRandom())
        i+=1

    plt.hist(values, bins=range(0,100+1,(100-0)/20)
    plt.suptitle('Random Numbers', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Range', fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('Frequency', fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
    return

def generateRandom():
    return np.random.randint(0,100)

if__name__=='__main__':
    plotRandomNumbers(1000)
```

I believe this should work however, for the plt.suptitle('Random Numbers', fontsize=20), it says invalid syntax. This for Python 3.7 by the way.

Comment: That is because you have a missing `)` in the line before `plt.suptitle` where you use `plt.hist`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the missing `)`, you also need to convert the step size in your `range` to integer type as

```
plt.hist(values, bins=range(0,100+1,int((100-0)/20)))
```

[image]